# Is there a method in turning user input into csv format?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

This is the example data that would be pasted into an input() prompt and ideally I would like it to be processed and made into a csv file through python:

```
,,,,,,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Expected,Expected,Expected,SCA,SCA,Passes,Passes,Passes,Passes,Carries,Carries,Dribbles,Dribbles,-additional
Player,#,Nation,Pos,Age,Min,Gls,Ast,PK,PKatt,Sh,SoT,CrdY,CrdR,Touches,Press,Tkl,Int,Blocks,xG,npxG,xA,SCA,GCA,Cmp,Att,Cmp%,Prog,Carries,Prog,Succ,Att,-9999
Gabriel Jesus,9,br BRA,FW,25-124,82,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,40,13,1,1,0,0.1,0.1,0.0,4,0,20,27,74.1,2,33,1,4,5,b66315ae
Eddie Nketiah,14,eng ENG,FW,23-067,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.1,2,0,4,4,100.0,1,4,1,0,0,a53649b7
Martinelli,11,br BRA,LW,21-048,90,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,38,21,0,2,1,0.6,0.6,0.1,1,0,24,28,85.7,1,34,5,3,4,48a5a5d6
Bukayo Saka,7,eng ENG,RW,20-334,90,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,52,23,3,0,3,0.2,0.2,0.0,2,1,24,36,66.7,2,37,8,2,2,bc7dc64d
Martin Ødegaard,8,no NOR,AM,23-231,89,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,50,22,2,1,2,0.1,0.1,0.0,2,0,30,39,76.9,5,28,3,1,2,79300479
Albert Sambi Lokonga,23,be BEL,CM,22-287,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,1,1,100.0,0,1,1,0,0,1b4f1169
Granit Xhaka,34,ch SUI,DM,29-312,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,60,5,0,2,3,0.0,0.0,0.0,4,0,42,49,85.7,6,32,2,0,0,e61b8aee
Thomas Partey,5,gh GHA,DM,29-053,90,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,62,25,7,1,2,0.1,0.1,0.0,0,0,40,47,85.1,5,26,4,0,1,529f49ab
Oleksandr Zinchenko,35,ua UKR,LB,25-233,82,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,64,16,3,3,1,0.0,0.0,0.3,2,1,44,54,81.5,6,36,5,0,0,51cf8561
Kieran Tierney,3,sct SCO,LBWB,25-061,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,2,4,50.0,0,1,0,0,0,fce2302c
Gabriel Dos Santos,6,br BRA,CB,24-229,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,5,1,1,2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,52,58,89.7,1,48,3,0,0,67ac5bb8
William Saliba,12,fr FRA,CB,21-134,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,3,1,2,2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,42,46,91.3,1,35,1,0,0,972aeb2a
Ben White,4,eng ENG,RB,24-301,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,61,22,7,4,5,0.0,0.0,0.1,1,0,29,40,72.5,5,25,2,1,1,35e413f1
Aaron Ramsdale,1,eng ENG,GK,24-083,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,24,32,75.0,0,21,0,0,0,466fb2c5
14 Players,,,,,990,1,1,0,0,10,2,2,0,599,158,25,17,21,1.1,1.1,0.5,18,2,378,465,81.3,35,361,36,11,15,-9999
```

The link to the table is: https://fbref.com/en/matches/e62f6e78/Crystal-Palace-Arsenal-August-5-2022-Premier-League#stats_18bb7c10_summary

I have attempted to use pandas dataframe but I am only able to export the first row of headers and nothing else (only the items before player).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would have been nice for you to include your attempt.

Pandas works just fine:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/matches/e62f6e78/Crystal-Palace-Arsenal-August-5-2022-Premier-League#stats_18bb7c10_summary'
df = pd.read_html(url)[10]

cols = [f'{each[0]}_{each[1]}' if 'Unnamed' not in each[0] else f'{each[1]}' for each in df.columns]
df.columns = cols
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_markdown())
|    | Player               |   # | Nation   | Pos   | Age    |   Min |   Gls |   Ast |   PK |   PKatt |   Sh |   SoT |   CrdY |   CrdR |   Touches |   Press |   Tkl |   Int |   Blocks |   xG |   npxG |   xA |   SCA |   GCA |   Cmp |   Att |   Cmp% |   Prog |   Carries |   Prog.1 |   Succ |   Att.1 |
|---:|:---------------------|----:|:---------|:------|:-------|------:|------:|------:|-----:|--------:|-----:|------:|-------:|-------:|----------:|--------:|------:|------:|---------:|-----:|-------:|-----:|------:|------:|------:|------:|-------:|-------:|----------:|---------:|-------:|--------:|
|  0 | Gabriel Jesus        |   9 | br BRA   | FW    | 25-124 |    82 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    1 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        40 |      13 |     1 |     1 |        0 |  0.1 |    0.1 |  0   |     4 |     0 |    20 |    27 |   74.1 |      2 |        33 |        1 |      4 |       5 |
|  1 | Eddie Nketiah        |  14 | eng ENG  | FW    | 23-067 |     8 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |         6 |       2 |     0 |     0 |        0 |  0   |    0   |  0.1 |     2 |     0 |     4 |     4 |  100   |      1 |         4 |        1 |      0 |       0 |
|  2 | Martinelli           |  11 | br BRA   | LW    | 21-048 |    90 |     1 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    2 |     1 |      0 |      0 |        38 |      21 |     0 |     2 |        1 |  0.6 |    0.6 |  0.1 |     1 |     0 |    24 |    28 |   85.7 |      1 |        34 |        5 |      3 |       4 |
|  3 | Bukayo Saka          |   7 | eng ENG  | RW    | 20-334 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    3 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        52 |      23 |     3 |     0 |        3 |  0.2 |    0.2 |  0   |     2 |     1 |    24 |    36 |   66.7 |      2 |        37 |        8 |      2 |       2 |
|  4 | Martin Ødegaard      |   8 | no NOR   | AM    | 23-231 |    89 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    2 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        50 |      22 |     2 |     1 |        2 |  0.1 |    0.1 |  0   |     2 |     0 |    30 |    39 |   76.9 |      5 |        28 |        3 |      1 |       2 |
|  5 | Albert Sambi Lokonga |  23 | be BEL   | CM    | 22-287 |     1 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |         2 |       0 |     0 |     0 |        0 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |  100   |      0 |         1 |        1 |      0 |       0 |
|  6 | Granit Xhaka         |  34 | ch SUI   | DM    | 29-312 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      1 |      0 |        60 |       5 |     0 |     2 |        3 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     4 |     0 |    42 |    49 |   85.7 |      6 |        32 |        2 |      0 |       0 |
|  7 | Thomas Partey        |   5 | gh GHA   | DM    | 29-053 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    1 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        62 |      25 |     7 |     1 |        2 |  0.1 |    0.1 |  0   |     0 |     0 |    40 |    47 |   85.1 |      5 |        26 |        4 |      0 |       1 |
|  8 | Oleksandr Zinchenko  |  35 | ua UKR   | LB    | 25-233 |    82 |     0 |     1 |    0 |       0 |    1 |     1 |      0 |      0 |        64 |      16 |     3 |     3 |        1 |  0   |    0   |  0.3 |     2 |     1 |    44 |    54 |   81.5 |      6 |        36 |        5 |      0 |       0 |
|  9 | Kieran Tierney       |   3 | sct SCO  | LB,WB | 25-061 |     8 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |         6 |       1 |     0 |     0 |        0 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     0 |     0 |     2 |     4 |   50   |      0 |         1 |        0 |      0 |       0 |
| 10 | Gabriel Dos Santos   |   6 | br BRA   | CB    | 24-229 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        67 |       5 |     1 |     1 |        2 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     0 |     0 |    52 |    58 |   89.7 |      1 |        48 |        3 |      0 |       0 |
| 11 | William Saliba       |  12 | fr FRA   | CB    | 21-134 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        58 |       3 |     1 |     2 |        2 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     0 |     0 |    42 |    46 |   91.3 |      1 |        35 |        1 |      0 |       0 |
| 12 | Ben White            |   4 | eng ENG  | RB    | 24-301 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      1 |      0 |        61 |      22 |     7 |     4 |        5 |  0   |    0   |  0.1 |     1 |     0 |    29 |    40 |   72.5 |      5 |        25 |        2 |      1 |       1 |
| 13 | Aaron Ramsdale       |   1 | eng ENG  | GK    | 24-083 |    90 |     0 |     0 |    0 |       0 |    0 |     0 |      0 |      0 |        33 |       0 |     0 |     0 |        0 |  0   |    0   |  0   |     0 |     0 |    24 |    32 |   75   |      0 |        21 |        0 |      0 |       0 |
| 14 | 14 Players           | nan | nan      | nan   | nan    |   990 |     1 |     1 |    0 |       0 |   10 |     2 |      2 |      0 |       599 |     158 |    25 |    17 |       21 |  1.1 |    1.1 |  0.5 |    18 |     2 |   378 |   465 |   81.3 |     35 |       361 |       36 |     11 |      15 |
```

Comment: Thanks! That works well however is it possible to have the headers above the columns to distinguish between attempted passes and attempted dribbles for example?

Comment: yup. see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

could you elaborate more?
maybe you could split the raw text by comma and then convert it to a dataframe
like:

```py
list_of_string = input.split(',')
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_string)
df.to_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is as proposed by [chitown88](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531259/9302488), however if you want to copy paste the data by hand into the terminal and get a csv you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
    contents = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(contents)
    df.to_csv(f"df_{int(datetime.now().timestamp())}.csv", index=None)
```

Start the Python script, paste the data into the terminal, press CTRL+D and press enter to export the data you pasted into the terminal into a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user input controlled while loop to get user input. Finally, you may exit depending on the user’s choice. Look at the code below:

```
user_input = 'Y'
while user_input.lower() == 'y':
    # Run your code here.
    user_input = input('Do you want to add one more entry: Y or N?')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most intuitive and understandable solution I could come up with uses of basic linear algebra to solve the problem which I find pretty neat. I recommend you to find an another way to parse the data. Check out beautifulsoup and requests.

```
import pandas as pd#for dataframe

data = '''
,,,,,,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Performance,Expected,Expected,Expected,SCA,SCA,Passes,Passes,Passes,Passes,Carries,Carries,Dribbles,Dribbles,-additional
Player,#,Nation,Pos,Age,Min,Gls,Ast,PK,PKatt,Sh,SoT,CrdY,CrdR,Touches,Press,Tkl,Int,Blocks,xG,npxG,xA,SCA,GCA,Cmp,Att,Cmp%,Prog,Carries,Prog,Succ,Att,-9999
Gabriel Jesus,9,br BRA,FW,25-124,82,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,40,13,1,1,0,0.1,0.1,0.0,4,0,20,27,74.1,2,33,1,4,5,b66315ae
Eddie Nketiah,14,eng ENG,FW,23-067,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.1,2,0,4,4,100.0,1,4,1,0,0,a53649b7
Martinelli,11,br BRA,LW,21-048,90,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,38,21,0,2,1,0.6,0.6,0.1,1,0,24,28,85.7,1,34,5,3,4,48a5a5d6
Bukayo Saka,7,eng ENG,RW,20-334,90,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,52,23,3,0,3,0.2,0.2,0.0,2,1,24,36,66.7,2,37,8,2,2,bc7dc64d
Martin Ødegaard,8,no NOR,AM,23-231,89,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,50,22,2,1,2,0.1,0.1,0.0,2,0,30,39,76.9,5,28,3,1,2,79300479
Albert Sambi Lokonga,23,be BEL,CM,22-287,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,1,1,100.0,0,1,1,0,0,1b4f1169
Granit Xhaka,34,ch SUI,DM,29-312,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,60,5,0,2,3,0.0,0.0,0.0,4,0,42,49,85.7,6,32,2,0,0,e61b8aee
Thomas Partey,5,gh GHA,DM,29-053,90,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,62,25,7,1,2,0.1,0.1,0.0,0,0,40,47,85.1,5,26,4,0,1,529f49ab
Oleksandr Zinchenko,35,ua UKR,LB,25-233,82,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,64,16,3,3,1,0.0,0.0,0.3,2,1,44,54,81.5,6,36,5,0,0,51cf8561
Kieran Tierney,3,sct SCO,LBWB,25-061,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,2,4,50.0,0,1,0,0,0,fce2302c
Gabriel Dos Santos,6,br BRA,CB,24-229,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,5,1,1,2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,52,58,89.7,1,48,3,0,0,67ac5bb8
William Saliba,12,fr FRA,CB,21-134,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,3,1,2,2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,42,46,91.3,1,35,1,0,0,972aeb2a
Ben White,4,eng ENG,RB,24-301,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,61,22,7,4,5,0.0,0.0,0.1,1,0,29,40,72.5,5,25,2,1,1,35e413f1
Aaron Ramsdale,1,eng ENG,GK,24-083,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,24,32,75.0,0,21,0,0,0,466fb2c5
14 Players,,,,,990,1,1,0,0,10,2,2,0,599,158,25,17,21,1.1,1.1,0.5,18,2,378,465,81.3,35,361,36,11,15,-9999
'''
#you can just replace data with user input

def tryNum(x):#input a value and if its a number then it returns a number, if not it returns itself back
    try:
        x = float(x)
        return x
    except:
        return x

rows = [i.split(',')[:-1] for i in data.split('\n')[2:-2]]#removing useless lines
col_names = [i for i in rows[0]]#fetching all column names
cols = [[tryNum(rows[j][i]) for j in range(1,len(rows))] for i in range(len(rows[0]))]#get all column info by transposing the "matrix" if you will
full = {}#setting up the dictionary
for i,y in zip(col_names,cols):#putting the data in the dict
    full[i]=y
df = pd.DataFrame(data = full)#uploading it all to the df

print(df.head())
```